# Why isn't the dd command making this drive bootable?

Tags: mac, usb, dd

I am trying to make a bootable Ubuntu flash drive on macOS Sierra using the `dd` command, but when the command finishes, I restart my computer and old `alt` and the flash drives doesn't come up as an option.

The commands I used were

```
sudo diskutil unmount /dev/disk1s2
sudo dd if=/Users/jordanbaron/Desktop/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/disk1s2 bs=1m
```

This is the output when I use the command `diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *32.0 GB    disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data                         31.8 GB    disk1s2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not used a Mac much, but it looks very much to me like you are writing the image to the wrong location.  A Linux ISO needs to be written to a disk, not a partition as you appear to be doing.

I'd try dd if=/users/jordanbaron/Desktop/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/**disk1** bs=1m